# Object Browser for .NET Core Development on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm using Visual Studio Code on Mac OS X to develop a series of .NET Core web APIs.

However, I'm missing the Object Browser from Visual Studio 2015 on Windows, and similarly missing .NET Reflector. Either of these utilities are essential for browsing .NET assemblies, to discover constructors, method signatures, class names, and other metadata

**Question**: What can I use on Mac OS X as a replacement for the Visual Studio Object Browser or .NET Reflector?

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio for Mac, this is called Assembly Browser. It can be accessed in the menu bar.

**Tools -> Assembly Browser**

Comment: yes, but there is no information about the project, you can just select it but nothing inside it like its c-tors, finalizers etc shows

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio for Mac, the information you ware looking for is located here:

**View -> Pads -> Help**

There you can see details on Basic Class Library, such as System > Console Class > Methods. Where you'll find eg. ReadLine. Tapping on this will launch a MonoDoc that will give you lots on in depth information that you would find in the Object Browser Windows Visual Studio equivalent.

Comment: but not for your project objects, this is documentation of mono, system etc libraries, not a detailed in depth view of your own objects such as its c-tors, finalizers etc that you can see in .NET Reflector

Answer (score 0):

Hover over any .NET type, and click command + LMB